# Displaying files that are group or world writeable in a home directory

Tags: scripting, ksh, aix

I'm trying to create a script that will display all the files that are group and world writeable in a home directory.

Warning: The script will run an endless loop of file not found if you run it locally.

```
#!/bin/ksh 
lsuser -a home ALL |cut -f2 -d= | while read HOMEDIR; do
if [ -d $HOMEDIR ]; then
ls -a $HOMEDIR | grep -Ev "^.$|^..$" | while read FILE; do
[[ "$(ls -ld ${FILE})" = @(????????w? *) ]] && print " WARNING ${FILE} is world wr
itable"
[[ "$(ls -ld ${FILE})" = @(?????w???? *) ]] && print " WARNING ${FILE} is group wr
itable"
done
else
echo "No home dir for $HOMEDIR"
fi
done
```

Any pointers?

Comment: what about using `find . -perm /022 -type f` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not commenting on your question instead, but I don't have enough reputation yet. Please read [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) carefully and use find as advised by Alex. Is there a specific reason you are not using find?